# Java: How to design collection using a superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, collections, reference

This is a practical question, but I am not sure if it has a practical answer. If you have a superclass with let's say 10 subclasses, what is the most simple way to put those 10 subclasses in a collection? Right now (this may be bad design), I have put them in a static collection field in the superclass.

The motivation for this question, however, came because I had obtained the identity of one of the fields of one of the subclasses, but I needed a reference to a different field in the same subclass.

For instance, let's say the subclass has the following fields:

```
public class SampleSubClass extends SampleSuperClass{
...
private Object1 o_1;
private Object2 o_2;
private Object3 o_3;
...
}
```

Somewhere else in the program, I have only the identity of o_2, and I wanted to get at o_3.
In theory, there might be an easier way than having to put all of the instances of SampleClass in a collection somewhere. For instance, perhaps in my dreams, there is a software language out there, where the superclass DOES carry information about its subclasses, and the superclass serves as a collection in and of itself.

But nevermind that. To me now, it seems like a good way to put the collection somewhere in the program, is to use a hashmap/hashtable, and to use it as a static member of the superclass.

Please tell me there is a better way. Is there any way to reference field A in an object by having only a reference to field B in an object?

For instance, say I have an ActionPerformed method, it has a source object that is contained in the ActionEvent object parameter. How would I find the instance of the class that owned/contained that source object? What is the best way to design this?

Comment: I think you're using terminology incorrectly, which makes your question confusing.  Generally, superclass/subclass refer to an *inheritance* relationship (i.e. `class Sub extends Super`), not a composition relationship.

Comment: thanks Oli, this question does talk about both inheritance and composition.

Comment: Hmm, in that case it's very unclear what you want to be able to do.  My best understanding is that given a reference to `o_2`, you want to be able to get a reference to `o_3`.  What does that have to do with sub/super-classes?

Comment: hi Oli, I agree it is confusing. Basically, I wanted to get a field A in a class while only holding information about a field B in class. Traditionally, the way to solve this is by using a collection. My question has two parts: (1) is there a way besides using a collection? And (2), if not, how to best use a collection? unfortunately, the question I posed is really two questions. But Adrian took a good shot at an answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native way to find the owner of a field given the object the field references. The JVM records the number of references pointing to each object so it can do garbage collection, but it doesn't keep track of the owners of the references.

You can store the values of all the fields in a `Map` which maps them to their owners:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Super
{
    static Map<Object, Super> owners = new IdentityHashMap<Object, Super>();
    // IdentityHashMap will not work with primitives due to autoboxing,
    // but HashMap requires all field values to have sensible implementations
    // of hashCode() and equals().

    /** Gets the owner associated with a field. */
    public static Object getOwner(Object field)
    {
        return owners.get(field);
    }

    /** Establishes ownership over a field. */
    protected void own(Object field)
    {
        owners.put(field, this);
    }

    /** Removes an ownership, but only if this is the owner. */
    protected void disown(Object field)
    {
        if (owners.get(field) == this) owners.remove(field);
    }

    /** Shorthand for disown(oldField); own(newField). */
    protected <T> T change(T oldField, T newField)
    {
        disown(oldField);
        own(newField);
        return newField;
    }
}

public class SubA extends Super
{
    protected String s;
    protected Integer i;

    public SubA(String aString, Integer anInt) { setS(aString); setI(anInt); }
    public void setS(String aString) { s = change(s, aString); }
    public void setI(Integer anInt) { i = change(i, anInt); }
    public String toString() { return "SubA(" + s + "," + i + ")"; }
}

public class SubB extends Super
{
    protected Object o;

    public SubB(Object anObject) { setO(anObject); }
    public void setO(Object anObject) { o = change(o, anObject); }
    public String toString() { return "SubB(" + o + ")"; }
}

public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s1 = "String1", s2 = "String2", s3 = "String3";
        Integer i1 = 111, i2 = 222;
        Object o1 = new Object(), o2 = new Object();

        SubA a1 = new SubA(s1, i1), a2 = new SubA(s2, i2);
        SubB b = new SubB(o1);

        p("s1 owner = %s", Super.getOwner(s1)); // SubA(String1,111)
        p("s2 owner = %s", Super.getOwner(s2)); // SubB(String2,222)
        p("s3 owner = %s", Super.getOwner(s3)); // null
        p("i1 owner = %s", Super.getOwner(i1)); // SubA(String1,111)
        p("i2 owner = %s", Super.getOwner(i2)); // SubA(String2,222)
        p("o1 owner = %s", Super.getOwner(o1)); // SubB(java.lang.Object@...)
        p("o2 owner = %s", Super.getOwner(o2)); // null

        p("s1 -> s3, o1 -> o2");
        a1.setS(s3);
        b.setO(o2);

        p("s1 owner = %s", Super.getOwner(s1)); // null
        p("s3 owner = %s", Super.getOwner(s3)); // SubA(String3,111)
        p("o1 owner = %s", Super.getOwner(o1)); // null
        p("o2 owner = %s", Super.getOwner(o2)); // SubB(java.lang.Object@...)
    }

    static void p(String fmt, Object... args)
    {
        System.out.format(fmt, args);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Or you could make the field values themselves maintain a reference to their owner, either through inheritance or using a wrapper class:

```
public class OwnableObject
{
    protected Object owner;

    public OwnableObject(Object anOwner) { owner = anOwner; }
    public Object getOwner() { return owner; }
    public void setOwner(Object anOwner) { owner = anOwner; }
}

public class MyString extends OwnableObject
{
    protected String str = null;

    public MyString(Object anOwner) { super(anOwner); }
    public String toString() { return str; }
    public void set(String aString) { str = aString; }
}

public class FieldWrapper<E> extends OwnableObject
{
    protected E value = null;

    public FieldWrapper(Object anOwner) { super(anOwner); }
    public E getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(E aValue) { value = aValue; }
}

public class Demo
{
    protected MyString s = new MyString(this);
    protected FieldWrapper<Integer> i = new FieldWrapper<Integer>(this);

    public void setS(String aString) { s.set(aString); }
    public void setI(int anInt) { i.setValue(anInt); }
    public String toString() { return "Demo(" + s + "," + i.getValue() + ")"; }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Demo d1 = new Demo();
        Demo d2 = new Demo();

        MyString f1 = d1.s;
        FieldWrapper<Integer> f2 = d1.i;
        OwnableObject f3 = d2.s;
        OwnableObject f4 = d2.i;

        d1.setS("one");
        d2.setS("two");
        d1.setI(1000);
        d2.setI(2000);

        p("f1 = %s, owner = %s", f1, f1.getOwner());
        p("f2 = %d, owner = %s", f2.getValue(), f2.getOwner());
        p("f3 = %s, owner = %s", f3, f3.getOwner());
        p("f4 = %s, owner = %s", f4, f4.getOwner());
    }

    static void p(String fmt, Object... args)
    {
        System.out.format(fmt, args);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering your direct question: how to easily define a collection containing a given set of classes?

```
public class ClassA {
    private final List<Class<? extends a>> knownSubclasses = Arrays.asList(ClassB.class, ClassC.class);
};
class ClassB extends ClassA {}
class ClassC extends ClassA {}
```

Answering your motivation: how to access a field in a subclass without declaring it for the super class?

```
public class SomeSuperclass {
    protected Object3 getObject3() throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
public class SomeSubclass extends SomeSuperclass {
     private final Object3 object3 = null;
     @Override
     protected Object3 getObject3() { return object3; }
}
```

Maybe recognize instances having an object3 by the use of interfaces

```
public interface MyClassWithObject3 { Object3 getObject3(); }

...
void someOperation(SomeSuperclass that) {
   if (that instanceof MyClassWithObject3) { ... }
}
```

You could also use named properties

```
void someOperation(SomeSuperClass that) {
    Object3 object3 = that.getProperty("object3");
}
```

Comment: thanks Adrian, that helps. To further clarify, what I am wondering is if you could 'tag' fields with the identity of the objects they belong to. I mean, they are already there within the class...why is there no meta-information about what instance of an object a field belongs to? Does that make sense? It's getting a little philosophical, but hopefully I am on point. The traditional solution to solving this kind of problem is by using a collection, but I am mostly wondering if there is another way, because using collections can be overkill sometimes.

Comment: @AlexMills oh, I guess I answered the wrong question then:-) You could use some sort of `Pair<Object3, SomeSuperclass>` type for the field instead of just SomeSuperclass,or maybe an `Object3` subclass that has a reference to the `SomeSuperclass` instance. I'm not sure though if such circular references are problem-free on their own.